# Mono-atomic gas particles coupled by spring forces don't care how many particles are involved?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, ideal-gas, partition-function

I calculated the partition function of $N$ classical atoms of identical mass $m$ who all experience a mutual spring forces with identical spring constant $k$. The Hamilton is
\begin{align}
H
=
\dfrac{1}{2m}
\sum_{j=1}^{N}
|\boldsymbol{p}_j|^2
+
\dfrac{k}{2}
\sum_{j=1}^{N}
\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}
|\boldsymbol{q}_j-\boldsymbol{q}_i|^2
\end{align}

I calculated the partition function as 
\begin{align}
Z
&=&
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\cdots
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
e^{-\beta H}
(d^3p_1 \cdots d^3p_N)
(d^3q_1 \cdots d^3q_N)
\\&=&
V T^{(3/2)N}
\left(
\left(
2m\pi k_B
\right)^N
\left(
\dfrac{2 \pi}{k}
\right)^{N-1}
N^{-N}
\right)^{3/2}
\end{align}

I discovered the equation of state is
\begin{align}
p
=
k_B T
\dfrac{\partial \ln(Z)}{\partial V}
=
\dfrac{k_B T}{V}
\end{align}
which states the pressure $p$, temperature $T$, and volume $V$ do not depend on the number of particles in the gas.

Why would a gas purely coupled by spring forces have an equation of state independent of the amount of gas particles? Also, how would such a gas behave in the real world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the calculation was done correctly (on first glance). However, that is not important here, just think about what you are doing: You have N particles all of which are mutually interacting via a super-long-ranged potential (Coulomb-interaction $\sim r^{-1}$ would be considered long-ranged, you are using a parabolic $\sim r^2$ potential). So, what you are defining is by all means a solid (a really, really compact one).  So let's have a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state#Equations_of_state_for_solids No $N$-dependence there either.

The physical reason is: there is no macroscopic entropy, what you can do with your ball of springs are the 6 rigid-body degrees of freedom (i.e. center of mass translation and rotation).

Comment: Should I include the full derivation? It is possible I might have made a mistake in the math. Thanks.